# Merge js object values from different data sets

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object

I have 2 data points Firebase and a local array of objects cointaining images and keys.

What I'd like to do is to check is the id from tha backend matches the local images keys and if true add the image to the user state together with the id.

```
const userAvatars = [
    { image: require('../images/user1.png'), key: 'user1' },
    { image: require('../images/user2.png'), key: 'user2' },
    { image: require('../images/user3.png'), key: 'user3' },
    { image: require('../images/user4.png'), key: 'user4' },
]
```

This is where I setState for users, which I'd like to have
`{id: userID, image: userAvatars.image}`

```
_createUsersList = () => {
    this.data = firebase.database().ref('filters/users');
    this.data.once('value').then(snapshot => {
        const items = [];
        snapshot.forEach((snapshot) => {
            items.push({
                id: snapshot.val(),
                image: snapshot.val() == userAvatars.key ? userAvatars.image : null
            });
        });
        this.setState({
            users: items 
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do

```
const matchedAvatars = userAvatars.filter((avatar) => {
 return avatar.key == snapshot.val();
});
if(matchedAvatars && matchedAvatars.length > 0){
    matchedAvatars.forEach((avtr) => {
        items.push({
            id: snapshot.val(),
            image: avtr.image
       })
   })
}
```

let know if this works.

Comment: Thanks @Vasanth but its working partially. That only returns the value of the first element as described in [Array.prototype.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)
I tried to loop it but didn't work

Comment: Try Array.prototype.filter it can return all matched avatars.

Comment: I have edited the answer. Not sure if this is what you are looking for. Try it out and let me know.